# Validate (and Query) XmlElement Content without OuterXML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I have a Web Method (within a SOAP Web Service) with a signature of:

```
public msgResponse myWebMethod([XmlAnyElement] XmlElement msgRequest)
```

I chose to use the `XmlElement` parameter after [reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480498.aspx) that it would allow me to perform my own **XSD validation** on the parameter.  The problem is that the parameter can be quite **large** (up to 80Mb of XML) so calling `XmlElement.OuterXML()` as suggested in the link isn't a very practical method.

**Is there another way to validate the XmlElement object against an XSD?**

More generally, is this an inappropriate approach for implementing a web service expecting large amounts of XML?  I've come across some hints at using SoapExtensions for gaining access to the input stream directly but am not sure this is the correct approach for my situation.

**Note:** Unfortunately, I'm chained to an existing WSDL and XSD that I have no power to alter which is why I went with a non-WCF implementation in the first place.

Comment: Why would the existing WSDL and XSD prevent you from using WCF?

Comment: I was told WCF wouldn't work with an existing Wsdl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example. Just pass your `XmlElement` to this method:

```
private static void TheAnswer(IXPathNavigable inputElement)
{
    var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemas.Add("http://foo.org/importvalidator.xsd",
                @"..\..\validator.xsd");
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
                       {
                           Schemas = schemas,
                           ValidationFlags =
                               XmlSchemaValidationFlags.
                                   ProcessIdentityConstraints |
                               XmlSchemaValidationFlags.
                                   ReportValidationWarnings,
                           ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
                       };
    settings.ValidationEventHandler +=
        (sender, e) =>
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e.Severity, e.Message);
    using (
        XmlReader documentReader =
            inputElement.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree())
    {
        using (
            XmlReader validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(
                documentReader, settings))
        {
            while (validatingReader.Read())
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```